# compilation :First argument was an invalid path = "message-{Date.now()}" Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain "."

Tags: reactjs

I got the following error compiling the code:

> ```
> Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path =
> "message-{Date.now()}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't
> contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

Instead of

```
"message-{Date.now()}"
```

use

```
`message-${Date.now()}`
```

Comment: always the same problem

Comment: 19 | addMessage = message =>{
  20 | const messages = { ...this.state.messages}
  21 | messages['message-${Date.now()}'] = message
> 22 | this.setState({messages})
  23 | }
  24 | render () {
  25 |   const messages = Object

Comment: use `\`` instead of `'`. This is a [backtick](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm).